# svg: Coordinates of a character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I have a `text` inside an svg which contains some string; is it possible to get coordinates (i.e. x, y) of a specific character? (say 100th character)

My intuition says that, yes it is but I don't know how, and searching in google brings irrelevant results (or I don't know the right keyword to search)

Comment: Hundredth character would be `textElement.getStartPositionOfChar(99);` (textElement being the text element, obviously)

Comment: See: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#DOMInterfaces

Comment: @RobertLongson - I find writing answers on the mobile app tedious :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SVGTextContentElement`](http://html5index.org/SVG%20-%20SVGTextContentElement.html) has an operation [`getStartPositionOfChar(unsigned long charnum)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#text-__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getStartPositionOfChar)

So in your case, given a text element in var `textElement` - you get the position of the 100<sup>th</sup> char using

```
textElement.getStartPositionOfChar(99);
```

Comment: thanks for the edit - my place was all over the head